# SFTP chroot jail on Centos system with Active Directory integration

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, ldap, sftp

I am trying to set up a SFTP chroot jail environment on one of our Centos, which is integrated with Active Directory for user authentication (set up with Realmd/oddjob).

I would like to chroot each user logging in (from a specific group) to their home directory, such as the below sshd_config snippet:

```
Match Group "sftponly"
 ChrootDirectory %h
 ForceCommand internal-sftp
 X11Forwarding no
 AllowTcpForwarding no
```

As it happens, user log in to the SFTP server fails with:

```
fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component
```

... as it's expecting the chroot directory to be owned by root and it's not, as the user's home directory is created on the fly and it's owned by the user, as in

```
drwx------ 2 test.user domain users 4096 Jul 24 16:18 test.user
```

Using a different chroot directory per user is a requirement.

Is there any way of having the home directories automatically being owned by root, on creation? Or any way of telling oddjob-mkhomedir to set the ownership to root?

Comment: please read the 2 links, first a security related bug which might not yet be fixed:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=995097
you can specific permissions in /etc/oddjobd.conf.d/oddjobd-mkhomedir.conf's 

2nd a discussion about this issue:
https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/sssd-users@lists.fedorahosted.org/thread/DKXLRZD3PDATOWFF3WPBCKN4WAHZXAJO/?sort=date

not certain it will help you, but it might be a good start where to look for a solution.